# Call to undefined function on function from same page as working functions

Tags: php

I have this file:

```
<?php
    define('SITH_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/new/IndiaCommunity/');

    function getLang()
    {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
        {
            setLang("he");
        }

        return $_COOKIE['lang'];   
    }

    function setLang($lang)
    {
        $date_of_expiry = time() + 604800; // One week.
        setcookie("lang", $lang, $date_of_expiry );
    }
?>
```

I then require this page in the index page.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
if (isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    getLang(); // no error
    setLang($_GET['lang']); // error
}
```

When I call the `getLang();` function I get `he` like I should,

but when I call `setLang("en");`

from the same page I called `getLang();`

I get the "Call to undefined function" error.
Why can I call the `getLang` but not the `setLang` which are both defined in the same page??

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling setLang()

Comment: Because you chose the dark side... (row 2) ;)

Comment: I do not see the connection from my typo in site to the error im getting

Comment: @imsiso `SITH` is the family name of the dark emperors, in starwars. i can't believe i'm explaining about, is that cen'ored in .ir?

Comment: I know that.. i don't see how does that cause the problem..

Comment: @Shomz is that fear in your voice? :) DavidLimkys what you see is not the error, it is PHP

Comment: What?? what does that mean ?

Comment: @metadings Haha, Shomz has left the building...
DavidLimkys Obviuosly the error is not in the piece of code you gave us, so I'd rather go check and isolate the rest of the code in order to debug it and probably find another typo instead of asking questions about the dark side and its connection to everything in the universe, including your script...

Comment: ok, i'm with you. try to uncomment and exclude other lines that may cause the problem, or change the functions order like imsiso says. in php you may get an error in line 500 when actually the error is a missing semicolon in line 300.

Comment: @metadings There is no outher code to show the first piece of code is the code im requiring in the second piece.

Comment: could you copy and paste the error, verbatim? (if getLang() works, then setLang() should work as well, given getLang calls setLang)

Comment: ha, it's the case of first time execution, that doesn't do what you expect. wait for my answer :)

Comment: @DavidLimkys Does any of the answers fix the undefined function error? I'm really eager to know

Comment: Thanks evryone, its been a long long night :D

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
define('THE_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/new/IndiaCommunity/');

function getLang()
{
    if (!empty($_GET['lang'])) {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
        setLang($lang);
    }
    else if (!empty($_COOKIE['lang']))
    {
        $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    }
    else {
        $lang = "he";
        setLang($lang);
    }

    return $lang;
}

function setLang($lang)
{
    $date_of_expiry = time() + 604800; // One week.
    setcookie("lang", $lang, $date_of_expir );
}
?>
```

Now use it like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$lang = getLang();
```

The difference to your code is mainly that you did expect that setcookie sets the value in $_COOKIE. Actually $_COOKIE array does only have the cookies you received by request, not the values you set for response. Other said, setcookie does set the $_COOKIE for the next request, it doesn't change the $_COOKIE for the current request.

By the way, I killed the SITH :) May the force be with you.

Comment: @imsiso yes, exactly. setcookie does set the $_COOKIE for the next request, it doesn't change the $_COOKIE for the current request.

Comment: Kudos for the Sith :D On the serious note, could this have been causing the `undefined function` error?

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.
The only thing i dont understand is on the first if, you are sending to setLang the value from the cookie but how can you know it is not null ?

Comment: @metadings what if you set `?lang=vader`? Never underestimate the power of the dark side of the force.

Comment: You guys are going to get me banned for starting an avalanche! :D

Comment: @DavidLimkys oops. that's a typo (the dark lord is bluring my mind ;)), i'm not testing your code, will you try it?

Comment: @imsiso ok, I'm starting to flag your spam comments - and it's not cool to steal answers and change one (not crucial) part of it

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ yeah, the validation is a good point. i see the preg_match in your answer, that's a good start (+1), however it doesn't qualify if the lang really exists. to be honest, i don't understand your explanation and dislike your code formatting.

Comment: @metadings Same here! I honestly soooo doubt that any of that will fix the original error (undefined function), but I hope I'm wrong... Let's hope David will reply soon...

Comment: @metadings if you use `?lang=english` it would not work if he was expecting a 2-digit language code. Also `?lang=DE` would not work if he's using lowercase only. Both technically languages.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ That's irrelevant, treat it as any string... that's not causing the error (expect for your regex, of course)

Comment: When i leave it like this i dont get an error but the cookie is not set to en, if i call the setLang outside of the config file i get the same error.

Comment: @Shomz ok dear Shomz just calm down and keep in mind that my english is not good and I dont understand what you mean than stealing? im just trying to help. and one other point there is no need to flag anything because im here and I will delete them.ok? any feeling now?

Comment: @DavidLimkys Does it behave the same way if you **only** use the code you've shown us (combined with an answer), nothing else?

Comment: I have more code in the site but this code runs first, it fails before it gets to the rest.

Comment: @metadings Sorry you don't understand my code. Assuming this is going to load some content out of a database, what happens in your code when someone says `?lang=en\';update%20languages%20set%20lang=\'xxx

Comment: Guys, let's try to fix this on the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29011/david

Comment: Please also read the article [PHP a fractal of bad design](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/), that will save you some nights. Also make use of notepad++ to save using UTF-8 without BOM and to have syntax highlighting. At least make sure in debug mode, that you really see anything, also runtime errors and warnings. Try to always use the latest PHP version. If you have a very old version, you may have to declare setLang before getLang, just because of the definition order.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing your arrays. And how you're pulling values and setting cookies. You were checking `if (isset($_GET['lang']))`, meaning if the address of the page doesn't end with `?lang=en` it doesn't retrieve your vars. You're not checking for a `$_COOKIE` on the page. You're only attempting to set a new cookie to 'he' if the cookie isn't set by trying to rewrite the $_COOKIE value. Then you were replacing that cookie with the value from `$_GET['lang']` assuming it's been set. If it's not, then you're setting an empty cookie. Someone could also set a cookie of '?lang=xxx' and break the code.

What this code does is it pulls the language from the `$_GET` var (a chance to reset the cookie). If they aren't resetting the cookie, then it's trying to pull the language out of the `$_COOKIE` var. If that doesn't work, then it's setting 'he' as the language default and setting the cookie.

**Try loading the code into the same page**

```
<?php

define('SITH_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/new/IndiaCommunity/');

    //This function cleans the input meaning
    //you can use lowercase letters exclusively.
    function getLang($lang)
    {
     //ISO 639-1 Code check - we're looking for a 2-digit code.
      if (!empty($lang)&&preg_match('!^[A-Za-z]{2}$!',$lang)){
      $lang = strtolower($lang);        
      } else {
        $lang='he';  
      }
        return $lang;   
    }

    function setLang($lang)
    {
        $date_of_expiry = time() + 604800; // One week.
        setcookie("lang", $lang, $date_of_expiry );
    }


    if(!empty($_GET['lang'])){
    $lang = getLang($_GET['lang']);

    //to give the option to reset the cookie
        setLang($lang); 

    } elseif (!empty($_COOKIE['lang'])){
            //Rather than trusting the cookie,
            //we're still checking it for
            //2-digit validity 
    $lang = getLang($_COOKIE['lang']);          
    } else {
    $lang = getLang('he');
    }

?>

<form action="#" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="lang" value="<?php echo $lang ?>" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Set Language" />
</form>
```

Comment: I dont understand why would this work, can you give a better explanation ?

Comment: Thank you, I was skeptical how could that solve the 'undefined function' issue, despite the messed up cookie stuff... Have you tested it?

Comment: @Shomz No I didn't initially... but after testing I added the else statement on the "other page." Now it works in Firefox.

Comment: Call to undefined function setLang() in \Index.php on line 7
No it does not :/

Comment: @DavidLimkys please answer this simply.did you try the thing I told you about the order of `setLang()` and `getLang()`?

Comment: @David Limkys what version of Apache and PHP are you running? Actually, are these files in different directories?